# How to affect other elements when one element is hovered (not sibling or parent)

Tags: javascript, css

I know we can affect sibling and child elements with css but doesn't find a solution to affect a not relative div in my page with hovered an other.

for exemple:

```
<div class="salutsalut">
salut
</div>
```

will affect:

```
<div class="miammiam">
miam
</div>
```

I tried this javascript:

```
const child = document.getElementsByClassName("salutsalut");
 child.onmouseover=function(){
     
     this.getElementsByClassName('miammiam').style="border:10px solid blue"

 }
```

If you have a different solution I'm open to,

and if something existe in css, this will be the best but don't think so.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

CSS selectors only allow you to style a descendant element (space), a child element (>), an adjacent sibling (+) or a general sibling (~). It's not possible to express any other type of relation in CSS.

So for cases where you want to give a specific style to an element whose relation to the one that's being hovered can't be expressed with valid selectors, then you would have to use Javascript.

TL;DR: in this case it's not possible with CSS.

Comment: Ok thanks you confirmed what I thought, His why I write an javascript in my message, because it doesn't work too

Comment: It seems you have a typo in "miamiam". It should be "miamiamt" to match the class in the HTML element.